# How to swipe horizontally inside stackNavigator screens?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a swipe navigation between different screens from a same `StackNavigator`

when i set `swipeEnabled:true` in `navigationOptions`, my app rather navigate between different Tabs.

I'd rather want to navigate inside a same stack from `Screen A` to `Screen B` for example.

How can i do this trick ?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same use case. I wanted a swipaeable `<StackNavigator>`. The solution I was able to find was to simulate a `<StackNavigator>` using a `<TabNavigator>`, or more specifically, using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator()`.

What I did was to create this tab (which is the only in the react-navigation 2 which allows `swipeEnabled`) and added `display: none` to its style. This way I can have a `<TabNavigator>` that behaves like a `<StackNavigator>`.

This is the code:

```
const SwipeableNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  FrontCard: FrontCardScreen,
  BackCard: BackCardScreen
},
{
  swipeEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    style: { display: "none" }
  }
});
```

And then just call `<SwipeableNavigator />` wherever you want.

Comment: To hide tab bar you can also provide custom tab bar component:

`tabBarComponent: () => null`. This way you won't have to render and then hide it with style