# React Native add gestures between 4 specific screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native app using `react-navigation`.
I would like to swipe gestures between 4 specific screens of a `StackNavigator`. From screen A, I want to access screen B on swipe left, screen C on swipe right and screen D on swipe up. And then from screen B for example, if I swipe right, I get back on screen A, etc.

I couldn't find anything in React Navigation 3.x that fitted my use case. Any recommandations, maybe in [react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler) ?

I looked up this link already: [How to swipe horizontally inside stackNavigator screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51483105/how-to-swipe-horizontally-inside-stacknavigator-screens)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your own custom navigator for that (probably based on tab router): https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html

Stack navigator is not made for the use case you're describing.